# Redcarpet 2.0.1

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, redcarpet

I'm following [this tutorial](http://railscasts.com/episodes/272-markdown-with-redcarpet) but it keeps failing saying "undefined method `new' for Redcarpet:Module". I have gem "redcarpet" in my Gemfile. The piece of code that is failing:

```
Redcarpet.new(@post.content).to_html
```

Comment: Just a quick sanity check... you ran 'bundle install' after changing your gemfile, right?

Answer (score 14):

Okay, it looks like Redcarpet 2 has completely changed the API. The following works:

```
markdown = Redcarpet::Markdown.new(Redcarpet::Render::HTML,
    :autolink => true, :space_after_headers => true)
raw markdown.render(@post_content.content)
```

Comment: +1 I prefer to use `markdown.render(@post_content.content).html_safe` which also works. Not a fan of using `raw` anymore.